# C#, get listbox item id?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, selecteditem

I'm new to C#,so I have a problem...I have a listbox in which I write data from database. I read ID, Name, Lastname,but I display only Name and Lastname. Now what I want is when I cliclk on item in list, I wanna get id. How?

```
Baza.Konekcija novaKonekcija = new Baza.Konekcija(); //kreiranje objekta
novaKonekcija.konekcijaBaza(); //pozivanje metode konekcijaBaza() iz klase Konekcija
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(); //kreiranje query objekta
query.Connection = Baza.Konekcija.myConnection; //povezivanje sa objektm baze
query.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Ime, Prezime FROM PrvaTabela ORDER BY Ime;"; //novi query
SqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader(); //pzivanje metode za iscitavanje
using (query)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        ime = reader.GetString(1);
        prezime = reader.GetString(2);
        id = reader.GetInt32(0);
        ListaImenika.Items.Add(ime + " " + prezime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx? The selectedItem-Property may be what you are for. Also you may add an onclick-event to your listbox where you put in your desired actions

Comment: You have two choices: Either query the database again for the id given a name (bad) or create a proper object model to populate the listbox with (good)

Answer (score 2):

`ListBox` stores objects, if you pass a string then original data will be lost. Fortunately you can use an object for that:

```
class ItemFromDb
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Ime { get; set; }
    public string Prezime { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Ime + " " + Prezime;
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    ListaImenika.Items.Add(new ItemFromDb 
    {
        Ime = reader.GetString(1),
        Prezime = reader.GetString(2),
        Id = reader.GetInt32(0)
    });
}
```

Note that if such object is used extensively you may want to make it safer (using private settings method and, maybe, putting some logic inside constructor, for example accepting a `SqlDataReader` parameter). Like this:

```
sealed class ItemFromDb
{
   public ItemFromDb(SqlDataReader reader)
   {
       Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
       Ime = reader.GetString(1);
       Prezime = reader.GetString(2);

       _displayName = Ime + " " + Prezime;
   }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Ime { get; private set; }
    public string Prezime { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _displayName;
    }

    private string _displayName;
}
```

Used like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
    ListaImenika.Items.Add(new ItemFromDb(reader));
```

Alternatively (if you don't want to override `ToString()` method) you can setup your `ListBox` to display a property value. Add this property:

```
public string DisplayName
{
    get { return Ime + " " + Prezime; }
    // get { return _displayName; }
}
```

Then set this property on your `ListBox` (in Designer):

```
ListaImenika.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
```

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24619388/1207195) for another example.

Answer (score -1):

I'd refer you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507354/how-do-i-get-at-the-listbox-items-key-in-c-sharp-winforms-app) possible solution, or you could simply use the listbox' `Tag` property to store your id there.

Comment: He has ONE tag property and multiple items, he should store an array of IDs (bad) or simply...use an object instead of a string (Tag isn't such useful this time)...

Comment: oh wow, totally got this question wrong haha my fault! true that, using the tag property would not lead to the goal.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding ListItem to ListBox.

like `ListaImenika.Items.Add(new ListItem("Text", "Value"));`

Replace "Value" with Id you want while populating your listbox. Like you have `id = reader.GetInt32(0);`

Then you can get the value later on when the item is selected.